# Numpy std (standard deviation) function weird behavior

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

From statistics point of view standard deviation when all values are equal should be 0.
For `arr1` result is as expected: `0`, but for `arr2` is `1.3877787807814457e-17` - very small but not `0`, which leads to issues with e.g. `zscore`.

Is this a proper behavior or weird bug?

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = [20.0] * 3
#[20.0, 20.0, 20.0]

arr2 = [-0.087] * 3
#[-0.087, -0.087, -0.087]

np.std(arr1) #0.0
np.std(arr2) #1.3877787807814457e-17
```

Comment: That is a floating point error. When the operations made in the std function the float32 values are not precise enough to represent theoretical values. As you see the std a very small number. see **np.mean(arr2)** it is -0.08700000000000001

Comment: I can't recollect example, but issue also occurs for large numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Numpy documentation for `std`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) states:

> The standard deviation is the square root of the average of the
> squared deviations from the mean, i.e., `std = sqrt(mean(abs(x - x.mean())**2))`.
>
> The average squared deviation is normally calculated as `x.sum() / N`,
> where `N = len(x)`. If, however, ddof is specified, the divisor `N - ddof` is used instead. In standard statistical practice, `ddof=1`
> provides an unbiased estimator of the variance of the infinite
> population. `ddof=0` provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the
> variance for normally distributed variables. The standard deviation
> computed in this function is the square root of the estimated
> variance, so even with `ddof=1`, it will not be an unbiased estimate
> of the standard deviation per se.
>
> Note that, for complex numbers, std takes the absolute value before
> squaring, so that the result is always real and nonnegative.
>
> For floating-point input, the std is computed using the same precision
> the input has. Depending on the input data, this can cause the results
> to be inaccurate, especially for float32 (see example below).
> Specifying a higher-accuracy accumulator using the dtype keyword can
> alleviate this issue.
>
> ```py
> a = np.zeros((2, 512*512), dtype=np.float32) 
> a[0, :] = 1.0 
> a[1, :] = 0.1 np.std(a)
> >>>0.45000005
> ```
>
> but for `float64`:
>
> ```py
> a = np.zeros((2, 512*512), dtype=np.float64) 
> a[0, :] = 1.0 
> a[1, :] = 0.1 
> np.std(a)
> >>>0.45
> ```

Comment: Should `np.std` in the first place check for "equality" (if true return 0.0)? I think it would avoid in such case rounding issue.

Comment: @QuantChristo Yes, it does not seem to examine equality.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it and got same results.
This says it's a bug for Numpy. It seems this happens when you use small numbers.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8207